# Measure Division in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am coming across an issue while dividing two measures "Spend running total" and "Total Invoiced Amount", which are calculated as :

**Spend running total** (numerator)= VAR InvoicedAmount =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Invoiced Amount]) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( [Invoiced Amount] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( [Vendor name] ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Invoiced Amount] ) >= InvoicedAmount )
        )
    )

**Total Invoiced Amount**(Denominator) = SUM([Invoiced Amount])

The division is not evaluated and I don't see a line for that in the chart, but when I replace it with the hard coded value, it evaluates and can be seen in the chart.

Am I missing something? Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Post your "division" measure formula.

Comment: Mike, thanks for responding. I was able to resolve the issue by creating a quick measure that creating "Totals" for category; in this case for "Vendor Name" which resulted in aggregating the "Invoice Amount" field by Vendor Name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding. I was able to resolve the issue By creating a quick measure by creating "Totals" for category in this case for "Vendor Name" which resulted in aggregating the "Invoice Amount" field by Vendor Name. Here's the complete formula :
**% Running Total = [Spend running Total]/[Invoiced Amount total for Vendor** name], where 
**Spend running Total** = VAR InvoicedAmount =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Invoiced Amount]) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( [Invoiced Amount] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( [Vendor name] ),
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Invoiced Amount] ) >= InvoicedAmount )
        )
    )

**Invoiced Amount total for Vendor name** = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM([Invoiced Amount]),
    ALL([Vendor name])
)

This solved the issue of division for me.